# Is it a good idea to update hash salt every login?

Tags: php, security, hash, salt

I want to make a secure website. Is updating the password salt every time a user logs in a good idea?

Edit: I additionally use a global salt, which is hard coded.

Comment: Are you on about using salt with a hashed password? The salt/encryption type should be established prior to the creation of accounts.

Comment: @DarylGill: The salt should be random and not the same for all passwords. Otherwise a single leakage of the salt will allow an attacker to compute rainbow tables for your site.

Comment: If you want to increase security you can add an additional step like XOR the salt for password with some additional string before using it for checking user login, save salt characters in the db in a different order than one used for checking passwords etc. Possibilities are limitless and it will make it pretty much impossible to get your passwords based on your db content only attacker would need access to your source code too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it makes no sense at all.

The purpose of salting hashes is to make them unique even if the original password is the same. This avoids e.g. rainbow table attacks or re-using a stolen hash on another website where the hash is sufficient to login (happens with bad remember-me implementations).

Assume an attacker got the stored password hash from your database. This usually means that he knows both the salt and the final hash. Now he can already brute-force this single password. Assuming there are no collisions he'll end up with the actual password of the user when the brute-force attack succeeds. And that one will work no matter what salt is used at this moment.

For more information about salting I suggest you to read [this excellent answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17435/427) on [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If attacker knows both the salt and the final hash he still needs to know the method used for creating the final hash and if he was able to get only the db content without accessing the source code we could still make it pretty much impossible for him to get the passwords.

Comment: Security by obscurity is bad. Besides that, if the guy creates an account with a known password he can most likely figure out what method you used.

Answer (score 2):

A new salt should be randomly generated for each user and each time they change their password **as a minimum**. I'm not sure if generating a new one each login is a good idea. It seems overkill and not provide any significant extra security.

You could try using an extra static site wide secret key.

In this case even your DB is  compromised, the hash and salt will be available. But the hacker will need access to local files to gain your static key.

hash(hash(salt + secret_key) + password)